# Itextsharp cannot open files with password if 128 bit rc4

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, encryption, itext

I have password protected pdf files that I'm trying to open to disable the password protection.  I have been able to do it with samples that are 128 bit aes but most of the files I will be dealing with in production are 128 bit rc4.  Whenever I try the following code on 128 bit rc4 it failes and gives me the error: Bad User Password.

```
try
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(InputFile, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(password));
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);
         stamper.Close();
         reader.Close();
         File.WriteAllBytes(OutputFile, memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(InputFile + " ::::: " + password + " ---> " + ex.Message);
}
```

For sample pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDisLjTqrx8QnFQQ013SFhmdGM/edit?usp=sharing
pass on file is: 123456 *obvious this is just for testing purposes ;)*

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Also: you shouldn't open the file with the *user* password, you need the *owner* password.

Comment: Itextsharp 5.5.1, at the moment there is no set owner password as I believe that is what it defaults to when you setup user/owner password to the same.  I can setup a separate owner password if you think that would be the cause of the issue?  Thanks.

Comment: If you create a PDF without an owner password, there is a chance that a random owner password is generated. That could explain the problem...

Comment: I've tested: there is indeed a problem opening the document with iText. I don't know the nature of the problem. I can perfectly open other documents that use 128-bit RC4 encryption using iText(Sharp).

Comment: I have tried it by having a different password but it still does not work.   Link for new file with separate owner password (xoxo) >>>>https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDisLjTqrx8Z1VSTW5ESEw3Sjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do i need to specify somewhere that it's 128-bit RC4 for it to work maybe?  I mean we're using the same ddl and that code snippet is pretty much 95% of the current code on the project so there isn't anything really affecting it so I don't understand why it's not working for me.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I've got the 1.6 spec in front of me, section 3.5.2. Right above table 3.20 it says "PDF integer objects are represented internally in signed twos-complement form. Since all the reserved high-order flag bits in the encryption dictionary's P value are required to be 1, the value must be specified as a negative number." The OP's `/P` value is set at `4294967292` and (if my math is correct) it should be `-4`. If I go to `SetupByUserPassword` in `PdfEncrption.cs` and manually change this to `-4` decryption succeeds. It looks like `PdfNumber.IntValue` is truncating the invalid value.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have changed that value and indeed it has worked!  Also the /P value only seems to affect decrypting programmatically as if I do this manually from Adobe Pro it decrypts without a problem.  Do they have special statement to maybe default to a specific value for P?

Comment: iTextSharp uses an `Int32` to hold the permissions which maxes out at `2,147,483,647`. When .Net converts from your string of `4294967292` it starts as a `Float` and then .Net tries to cast it to `Int32` but per spec it fails and returns an "unspecified value of the destination type". The `IntValue` should probably have either a `Int32.MaxValue` guard or a `checked{}` inside. If I understand the spec, your value is technically incorrect but the parsers that Adobe (and others) are using seem to have wider types that can account for it.

Comment: If `mPDF` is the only producer doing (from your first PDF posted) and if I understand the spec correctly, this might really be a bug in their code.

Comment: I grabbed the src for the itextsharp and did a dirty hack to just change the int32 to an int64.  There wasn't any compile errors and it seemed to solve the issue with the other pdfs from the other source, though the ones generated by that mPDF library still won't go through without setting a -4 value to their P.  I'm guessing there must be more to it but I don't want to delve too much into it at this point. I was mainly just interested in making something quick and simple to disable passwords after receiving the pdfs.

Comment: I'll create a ticket on the internal (paid) support system at iText. I know it's a problem for mPDF (I guess they don't have professional support), but we may decide to be tolerant towards faulty PDFs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(comments to answer)*

This appears to be a problem with the mPDF library that produced the pdf in question. Per the spec, section 3.5.2:

> PDF integer objects are represented internally in signed twos-complement form. Since all the reserved high-order flag bits in the encryption dictionary's P value are required to be 1, the value must be specified as a negative number.

The PDF in question has a `/P` value of `4294967292` which according to the spec is incorrect. If my math is correct it should actually be `-4`. Changing the iTextSharp manually to use this `-4` permission for `SetupByUserPassword` in `PdfEncrption.cs` allows decryption to succeed.

iTextSharp uses an Int32 to hold the permissions which maxes out at `2,147,483,647`. When .Net converts from your string of `4294967292` it starts as a Float and then .Net tries to cast it to Int32 but [per the C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle) it fails and returns an "unspecified value of the destination type".

> When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type, the
>   value is truncated. If the resulting integral value is outside the
>   range of the destination value, the result depends on the overflow
>   checking context. In a checked context, an OverflowException is
>   thrown, while in an unchecked context, the result is an unspecified
>   value of the destination type.

Adobe and other libraries might be using a wider type like a 64-bit integer which is why they are able to open the PDF.

The solution for the OP was to change parts of iTextSharp's source from `Int32` to `Int64`. This OK for their very specific situation but I wouldn't recommend it for most people unless they have a good grasp of the crypto algorithms used. Ideally this should be fixed with mPDF and possibly iText could add support to handle this invalid value.